# 3D Plot Python input,time,output

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I would like to plot my Input Data(X), my time (y) and my output(Z) in 3D plot using matplot. I Found a Tutorial[mplot3d example code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html) but there is still a mistake i cant find.

mdot0 is my input Parameter. I want to solve my differential equations with odeint and save them in results.
This way results is 100x11 matrix for each mdot0.

Hope someone can help me

here is my code:

```
#############################################################################

start_time=0.
end_time=600
resolution=100
t=linspace(start_time, end_time, resolution)
N=100
number_of_equations=11

#############################################################################

def odefunk(equations_to_solve, Tu, t, input_data):
    T0=zeros(nT)+Tu
    solv=odeint(equations_to_solve,T0,t,args=(Tu,input_data,alpha,A,m,cp,Q,epsilon,PTC))-273.15
    return solv

mdot   =array([16.4*lmin, mdotL ,33.4*lmin, 0*50.3*lmin, 0.2*lmin])    
mdot0=linspace(10.4*lmin,16.4*lmin,N)
n_var=5


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for mdot[0] in mdot0:
    f=odefunk(basicsAuto.dTSystem, Tu, t, mdot)
    surf = ax.plot_surface(mdot[0], t,f[:,8] , rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(0., 25.)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
```

Comment: *but there is still a mistake i cant find* --- would you care to share what error message you get? Does it produce any plot? If so, what is wrong with it? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not get any error Message the Plot Figure is empty

Comment: Did you try a `plt.show()` at the end?